# Smooth Streaming Video from Blob Storage

Tags: azure, video-streaming, flash, blobstorage

I have an MVC 4 application that contains a view to show "Videos" from azure blob storage of MP4 format only. Currently I'm using MediaElment.js(or any typical flash player) as the video player. How can I play these videos in a smooth streaming or progressive download(Adaptive streaming) method. What are the configurations that I have to set in Azure to support streaming? Is there anything that I have to do before uploading MP4 file to blob storage?

I have gone through this link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/spazuretrainingcourse_spblobstorageazure.aspx and as far as I understood, Windows Azure Blobs Uploader is used to upload video files to azure and silverlight as the client. In my case, the video is uploaded from a seperate application so the manipulation of video file is not possible. So is there any way to implement streaming without any change and play it in a video player other than using silverlight ?.

Is it possible to do anything if I can change the media file while uploading?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you looked into Windows Azure Media Services? WAMES supports adaptive streaming from Blob Storage, and even provides a way to convert videos to the smooth streaming format with a little bit of effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been doing almost exactly this, but without the Adaptive Streaming (I'm dealing with video files of only 25mb or smaller). I am using JWPlayer for the front end in my web page, and the video is in Azure blob storage.

I'm using the pre-built windows binary ffmpeg.exe I uploaded it to Azure (put it in root of Worker Role project), then I use System.Diagnostics.Process in a WorkerRole to massage the video files. You could do the same to create the different quality versions you want.

So, when a user uploads a video my business logic layer plops a message in an Azure message queue, my worker role picks it up, copies the video onto Azure LocalStorage (LocalStorage is physical disk you can configure in your Azure project settings file), runs ffmpeg.exe over the file and then puts it back in blob storage.

Comment: Many Thanks. So as per your method, while uploading video file to blob storage you are converting the media file to stream content using ffmpeg and storing this stream content in blob.Right?

Comment: Not quite. AFTER upload to blob, I am copying the video file to a temp_folder, using ffmpeg to alter the encoding (but you can do many things with ffmpeg and I suspect you can use it instead of Expression Encoder to do what you want on the command line , server-side on your Azure instance) Then I put the altered video file back into blob storage.

Comment: ok. I'm ready to use FFMPEG to encode the video file(MP4) as needed. Now to make it stream to a player, what are thw steps to be done? ie Do I need to create something like a handler which can stream video to the player on demand? I want the video to start playing progressively(without waiting for the entire video to be downloaded). Do I need to set anything at the client side (player) or the server side?

Comment: 2. What is the encoding to be used for streaming? 3. hope all we need to do is set the source of the video in the player as the URI of the FFPMEG encoded file in the blob,right?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing, just set the Uri in the Player and it buffers automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm new to FFMPEG and video streaming process can you please tell me what should be the format for output file(for a command like this : ffmpeg -i input.mp4-b:v 64k output.avi)for a sample.Encoding the MP4 file to a MP4 output does make any sense?

Comment: Let's go to the chat rooms http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c I'm new to FFMPEG too.

Comment: If you dont mind, feel free to put in the conclussion from the caht in the answer. I was looking for the exact same thing and think you would get some votes for having a full answer.